# about hardware accelerator for video processing

Tags: linux, drivers, video, vlc-media-player, hardware-acceleration

If we enable hardware accelerator in the applications how the code flow happens to the hardware accelerator.If not how the flow will be?
e.g. if hardware accelerator is enabled then encoding and decoding of data will be done by hardware.from applications a VA API will be used to call to video accelerator driver and from there drm library and from there drm driver and then drm driver controls hardware accelerator.
i am adding architecture image below.

is this understanding is correct? reply your understanding and any mistakes in this approach and correct approach.

and one more question that is, I have choosen vlc player to play a hdr video(stored in compressed format in memory) and it uses hardware accelerator to decode as usual cpu fetches content location and it needs to send to accelerator to decode video contents how this process will happens.(if it is audio some i2s modules will be used to send data to codecs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different programming interfaces for GPU-hardware acceleration of video processing. VAAPI is one, but others including the prominent NVENC / NVDEC exist and are widely used.

In all cases it is the job of the CPU to make the data available for the GPU - this can be pumping, DMA, page flipping and others, depending on the API used and whether there exists a common address space.

With decompression, depending on the workflow, the decompressed image might never be given back into the CPU domain, but might directly be displayed.

Comment: I like your answer Eugen Rieck. But in the last paragraph you are saying that the decompressed image might never be given back into the cpu domain here my doubt is how a compressed video will be stored in memory without involvement of cpu.

Comment: @kingNag the **de**compressed image might never be given back, but displayed! The **compressed** image was fetched by the CPU before.